# Solidity - String Template Literal

Tags: ethereum, solidity, remix, erc20, binance-smart-chain

How do I use string template literals on Solidity like JavaScript offers out of the box?

I need to write a multiline string in my ERC20 and would like to leverage something that doesn’t require me writing a bunch of `/n`

i.e.

```js
const myLongAndMultiLineVariable = `

1- Chicken picanha cow ham tongue beef ribs flank prosciutto jerky pork chop leberkas shoulder. 

2- Pork chop jowl meatloaf andouille swine buffalo prosciutto brisket. Biltong filet mignon 

3- chislic. Salami boudin sirloin pork belly short ribs pastrami swine bacon.

`
```

I'm new to this space, A code example showing the **output**, (how the string looks like) would be greatly appreciated it.